# How to run async function in FastAPI only once at a time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, fastapi

I'm new to FastAPI and asyncio and don't know how to realise this.
I have an endpoint, when called, it should start an AI prediction that takes about 40s in the background.

```
async def asyncio_test_prediction():
    print("Starting asnycio func")
    time.sleep(30);
    print("Stopping asyncio func")

@app.get('/sempos/start')
async def start_prediction():
    asyncio.ensure_future(asyncio_test_prediction())

    return {
        "state": "Started"
    }
```

This is the only way I managed for it to work. The EP function doesn't really need to be async but without it it doesn't work.

Now, I also want to ensure that "asyncio_test_prediction" is only called when it's not already running.

I read that this is possible with `task.done()` but I'm not sure how to initialize and store it. Or is there a better option?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest changing the expected behavior of your API.

How about having two endpoints:

- `'/sempos/start'` - starts the AI prediction and immediately returns the `id` of the calculation
- `'/sempos/result/{id}'` - gives a generic message if calculations aren't done, else gives the calculation results JSON

This way you can:

- Leverage the speed of FastAPI
- Use the flexibility of asyncio
- Fit your use case

What do you think?

Comment: I will look into it, hope I can manage. But to which ID are you refering to? And do you maybe know of an example with similar procedure?